# Getting Error: no section 'ChromeDriver' when using ChromeDriverManager().install() in exe file

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

I'm automating one of my regular processes by making a tool which uses Selenium. When I run the script in pyCharm, it works. But after converting it to an executable, it is throwing the error code below.

I looked at and tried some solutions available on the internet but I still can't get it resolved.

I have made two .py files, one main file calls another .py file. I enter the info into the GUI and when I press the submit button, it calls the 2nd file which has the code for downloading the required ChromeDriver version. When the line "ChromeDriverManager().install()" executes, it throws the below error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 

options = Options()
download_dir = r"C:\Users\{}\Documents\Downloaded_Report\\".format(user)
prefs = {'download.default_directory': download_dir, "directory_upgrade": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),
                          chrome_options=options)
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
  File "AutoSpeedScript.py", line 28, in send_info_to_download_report
  File "openPBMSite.py", line 197, in get_info
  File "site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 15, in __init__
  File "site-packages\webdriver_manager\driver.py", line 45, in __init__
  File "site-packages\webdriver_manager\driver.py", line 18, in __init__
  File "site-packages\webdriver_manager\config.py", line 28, in __getattr__
  File "site-packages\webdriver_manager\config.py", line 21, in get
  File "configparser.py", line 780, in get
  File "configparser.py", line 1146, in _unify_values
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'ChromeDriver'
```

Comment: Thanks @halfer for editing my question, I'll take care of these things now onward.